# Java specific image downloader with multiple URL's

Tags: java, eclipse, image, web, text-files

I can't figure out how to reference a specific line of text in a txt file. I need a specific image from a specific list of URL's and I am trying to generate the URL's by concatenating a URL prefix and a search number from a list of numbers in a txt file. I can't figure out how to reference the txt file and get a string from a line number.

```
package getimages;
public class ExtractAllImages {

public static int url_to_get = 1;
public static String urlupc;
public static String urlpre = "http://urlineedimagefrom/searchfolder/";
public static String url2 = "" + urlpre + urlupc + "";

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        while(url_to_get > 2622){

        String line =     Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file_on_my_desktop.txt")).get(url_to_get);
        urlupc = line;
        url2 = "" + urlpre + urlupc + "";

        String webUrl = url2;
        URL url = new URL(webUrl);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        HTMLEditorKit htmlKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
        HTMLDocument htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument) htmlKit.createDefaultDocument();
        HTMLEditorKit.Parser parser = new ParserDelegator();
        HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback callback = htmlDoc.getReader(0);

        parser.parse(br, callback, true);

        for (HTMLDocument.Iterator iterator = htmlDoc.getIterator(HTML.Tag.IMG); iterator.isValid(); iterator.next()) {

            AttributeSet attributes = iterator.getAttributes();
            String imgSrc = (String) attributes.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.SRC);

            if (imgSrc != null && (imgSrc.endsWith(".jpg") || (imgSrc.endsWith(".png")) || (imgSrc.endsWith(".jpeg")) || (imgSrc.endsWith(".bmp")) || (imgSrc.endsWith(".ico")))) {
                try {
                    downloadImage(webUrl, imgSrc);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }

 public static String right(String value, int length) {
     return value.substring(value.length() - length);}

 private static void downloadImage(String url, String imgSrc) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            if (!(imgSrc.startsWith("http"))) {
                url = url + imgSrc;
            } else {
                url = imgSrc;
            }
            String webUrl = url2;
            String imagename = right(webUrl , 12);
            imgSrc = imgSrc.substring(imgSrc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            String imageFormat = null;
            imageFormat = imgSrc.substring(imgSrc.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            String imgPath = null;
            imgPath = "C:/Users/Noah/Desktop/photos/" + urlupc + ".jpg";
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            image = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
            if (image != null) {
                File file = new File(imgPath);
                ImageIO.write(image, imageFormat, file);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

My error is in setting the String line, My txt file has 2622 lines and I can't reference the file on my desktop and im not sure how to set the file path to my desktop? Sorry I'm not good at java.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood you don't know how to access a file that is on your Desktop. Try doing this:

```
String path = "C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name")  + "\\Desktop\\" + fileName + ".txt";
```

Let me explain. We are using

```
System.getProperty("user.name")
```

to get the name of the user, if you don't want to use it then you can replace it with the name of your user. Then we are using

```
"\\Desktop\\"
```

to acess the Desktop, and finally we are adding the

```
fileName + ".txt"
```

to access the file we want that has the extension '.txt'.